# Codeigniter email not rendering as html in some clients

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have a web app that is sending emails via the code igniter mail library.

I'm receiving reports that some customers are recieving the source code of the email rather than the rendedered html. This is not the case in gmail which appears to work fine.

This is apparently how it renders in mac mail.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

 <html lang=3D"en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8">
```

I have set the content type like so:

```
 $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
 $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
```

What's confusing is why it's only some clients that render like so.

**EDIT:**

Here is the PHP that sends the email.

The client that is receiving them is also receiving html emails from shops etc perfectly fine.

```
private function sendQuoteEmail($id) {

    // Get request data based on $id and set variables for email

    $singleRecord = $this->vehicleRequests->fetch_by_id($id);

    $email = $singleRecord->email;

    $data = array(
        'id' =>$id,
        'name'=>$singleRecord->name,
        'price' =>$singleRecord->price,
        'make' =>$singleRecord->make,
        'model' =>$singleRecord->model
    );

    // Send the email
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
    //$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('xxx@xxx.com', 'xxx');
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject('Your Quote');

    $email = $this->load->view('email/quote_email', $data, TRUE);

    $this->email->message($email);

    $this->email->send();

}
```

Comment: This sounds like it is a problem with their email. Can you ask them if they get HTML emails from other sources? Maybe a setting is wrong in their preferences? If it is working in GMAIL the HTML is getting out correctly

Comment: Maybe post the raw email that shows up broken, and how about the PHP that generates it? Right now the best anyone can say about this is "yep, that's broken."

Comment: @Sammitch post has been updated and the client is receiving html emails fine. Just not this one.

Comment: Different rules apply to different clients/providers. `1) GMAIL does not allow stylesheets at all, everything must be inline styles.` `2) Yahoo allows stylesheets.` `3) Both will occasionally misinterpret code as being malicious and you will just randomly lose a style declaration.` The point of this comment is that it is very tough to tell what an email client is doing unless you have direct access to the email client. Maybe it's even being parsed before it hits their Mac.

Comment: Ok. If I get access to the client. What should I check for? I've included how it looks in the op.

Comment: Check for everything. May I ask why is `//$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';` commented out and where is `3D` coming from in `<html lang=3D"en">`? What is your `quote_email` view doing?

Comment: Maybe you need to send them a simple email like `$email = '<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><title>Test email</title></head><body><div style="padding:20px; background-color:#0000ff; color:#ffffff;">Testing DIV</div></body></html>';` and see what happens